# Hide some fields from EditForm

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, external-content-type, list-form, external-list

I have some troubles with EditForm in Sharepoint.
In SPD 2010 i have created External Type and defined CRUD method for him. I want to show in Disp form all item fields, but in Create and Edit form only fields subset, i.e. some fields "ReadOnly".

When i was creating "Create" and "Edit" methods in SPD 2010 operation constructor, i choose only those fields that really required.

When i open "NewItem" from in browser in Create from that's work, i see only subset fields, but in "Edit" from i see all fields.

What's wrong, please help.
I need to show subset fields in EditForm. It will be great if i could do this in SPD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, If you want to hide some fields in UpdaterForm, but to show them in DispForm, you should mark this fields as readOnly in SPECIFIC finder method. It's work.